# MetaSearch Gem overrides the search method with the Tire Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've added a fulltext searching database to my existing webapp that is built with Rails and uses the active_admin gem. The fulltext database is built on elastic search and uses the Tire gem. The active_admin gem has a dependency requirement of the metasearch gem which defines the Model.search method.

The problem is that the metasearch gem overrides the search method for the tire search gem and I can't seem to alias the search method in the tire gem back into the model. Does anyone know how I can do this?

-- Solution --

Update: The solution is to setup an initializer to add the following method:

```
def search_for(*args,&block)
  tire.__send__(:search, *args, &block)
end
```

Comment: How exactly did you add this method to Tire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a working solution. Basically, you need to just set the search method to be called `search_for` instead of `search`.

Create a helper file called tire_helper.rb within app/helpers.

```
module TireHelper

  def search_for(*args,&block)
    tire.__send__(:search, *args, &block)
  end

end
```

And for each model that uses tire then use this:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base

  extend TireHelper
  include Tire::Model::Search
  include Tire::Model::Callbacks

  mapping do
    # your mappings
  end

end
```

You can now search normally on your model(s) with the following method:

```
# with a string
query = Model.search_for('string')

# or with a block
query = Model.search_for do
  #any of the same block stuff that Tire.search provides
end
```

Comment: very useful! I wish I could give you more than one upvote for this

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `MyModel.tire.search("string")` without any helper.